# SwiftUI: No such Module 'FirebaseAuth'

Tags: swift, swiftui, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I've run into a strange issue when trying to setup Firebase sign in with Apple functionality in my app.

It is required to import `FirebaseAuth` for `OAuth` functionality. When I try importing it I get the error : "`No such Module 'FirebaseAuth'`". I have added the package dependencies with package manager and FirebaseAuth is there... but it still gives the error. See screenshot below.

[image]

Simply importing `Firebase` does not give an import error, however I still get errors when trying to use the Authentication functionality. See screenshot below[image]

I've looked for solutions elsewhere but others who have had the same issue as me used Cocoapods to install the packages so their solutions don't apply here.

I am using Xcode 13.0

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I fixed the issue by adding FirebaseAuth dependency in build phases:
[image]